# Laravel Validation If checkbox ticked then Input text is required?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have been reading Laravel validation documentation. I am not clear how to combine two rules.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="has_login" value="1">

<input type="text" name="pin" value="">
```

If `has_login` checkbox is ticked then Input text `pin` value is required.

If `has_login` is not ticked then Input text `pin` is not required.

Laravel Validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
          'has_login' => 'accepted',
          'pin' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use required_with or required_if

> `required_with:foo,bar`
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

```
return [
      'has_login' => 'sometimes',
      'pin'       => 'required_with:has_login,on',
];
```

--

> `required_if:anotherfield,value`
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

```
return [
      'has_login' => 'sometimes',
      'pin'       => 'required_if:has_login,on',
];
```

--

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

--

Also, if the checkbox `has_login` is not checked, it will not send as part of the form submission

Comment: To improve your answer. You need provide example code rather then copy and paste from Doc.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back added :)

Comment: didn't know about this method. Thanks.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back not the docs, when I post checkbox values and see the data using `$request->all()`, if the checkbox is ticked, then the value is `on`, if not ticked then it doesn't appear in the submitted input array, if this is wrong please let me know and i will update my answer

Comment: Since in this question there is only 1 field that needs to be examined, a `required_if` is the best option.