# Conditional validation with radio button, another input is required when radio button value is yes, else nullable

Tags: laravel, validation, radio-button

I have two radio button with value="YES" and value="NO". I want to make my next input text to be required if the selected radio button have a YES value, else the next input text is nullable

I already tried this 
[Laravel Validation If checkbox ticked then Input text is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525613/laravel-validation-if-checkbox-ticked-then-input-text-is-required)
But i think it is only work on checkbox and don't work with radio button. Here are my codes:

**View**

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>If yes, student agree to the accommodation prepared by International Office</b></td>
                    <td><input  type="radio" name="opt_acc" size="20" value="YES"/> YES</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b>If no, please state where you plan to stay in Indonesia:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="opt_acc" size="20" value="NO"/> NO</td>
                </tr>
                    <td><b>Address</b><hr>
                        <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address_acc" size=50"></td>
                    <td><b>Contact Person (Name/Phone)</b><hr>
                        <input placeholder="Name & Phone" type="text" name="cp_acc" size="25"></td>

            </table>
```

**Validation rules**

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
      // Accomodation
        'opt_acc' => 'required|in:YES,NO',
        'address_acc' => 'required|string',
        'cp_acc' => 'required|string'
    ];
}
```

I expect that the flow would be like this:

```
 if (opt_acc == YES) {
     'address_acc' => 'required|string',
     'cp_acc' => 'required|string'
  }
  else {
  'address_acc' => 'nullable|string',
  'cp_acc' => 'nullable|string'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'opt_acc' => 'required|in:YES,NO',
        'address_acc' => 'sometimes|nullable|required_if:opt_acc,YES|string',
        'cp_acc' => 'sometimes|nullable|required_if:opt_acc,YES|string'
    ];
}
```

Comment: It returns validation error message like "The address acc must be a string." Should i remove the string validation? If i do, when it is really required it won't validate those attributes as a string

Comment: You could use `alpha`. Updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: It returns "The cp acc may only contain letters."

Comment: I mean it would be nullable, so user may skip the text input without fill it when radio button is YES

Comment: @VickySultan i just updated my answer. Plz take a look